# How to activate the "nofollow" property of htmlpurifier on Trsteel's Ckeditor Bundle (symfony2)?

Tags: symfony, ckeditor, symfony-2.3, nofollow

Using Trsteel's Ckeditor Bundle for SYMFONY 2, I am looking to add rel="nofollow" to link tags. Technically, that can be done using a custom config file for Ckeditor, but I would rather use the native nofollow attribute provided by htmlpurifier. Unfortunately, I can not find any way to access the configuration option of htmlpurifier ! Any idea ?

Comment: Trsteel's dev told me they will eventually add the feature to pass the config options down to htmlpurifier !